# How do you remove a hard drive's GPT Protective Partition without compromising its functionality?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, gpt

I recently bought an Iomega NAS drive but I want to install my own operating system on it. I connected the hard drive to my computer with a SATA to USB casing but under disk management it says it is a GPT Protective Partition. How can I remove the partition and install my own OS while still being able to run in the Iomega NAS casing?

Comment: You're a Windows XP user?

Comment: @zero2cx no, 8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about NAS-specific issues, but if the disk has no data you can use most MBR partitioning tools to do the job. Since you mention "8" (presumably Windows 8), you can see [Microsoft's official documentation on the topic,](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737510%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for example.

If the disk already holds data, you can use [GPT fdisk (gdisk)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) to convert GPT to MBR while preserving your existing partitions.

Note that disks bigger than 2TiB pretty much require GPT; MBR maxes out at 2^32 sectors, which works out to 2TiB, given 512-byte sectors.